# Golang Data Race, with 66 exit status

Tags: go

I have the following code, and I am having data race.
The Round function periodically check runs the function to delete the contents of the map
As I read here: [Is it safe to remove selected keys from Golang map within a range loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23229975/is-it-safe-to-remove-selected-keys-from-golang-map-within-a-range-loop)

Removing the data from map is safe, but I am having data race

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type City struct {
    ID string
}

type Map struct {
    sync.RWMutex
    Data map[string]City
}

var done = make(chan struct{})

func (m *Map) Round() {
    for {
        select {
        case <-time.After(2 * time.Second):
            for i, v := range m.Data {
                fmt.Println("-----", v)
                delete(m.Data, i)
            }
        case <-done:
            println("bye")
            break
        }
    }
}

func (m *Map) Add(id string, h City) {
    m.Lock()
    m.Data[id] = h
    m.Unlock()
}

func main() {
    m := Map{}
    m.Data = make(map[string]City)

    m.Data["Ottowa"] = City{"Canada"}
    m.Data["London"] = City{"GB"}
    m.Data["malafya"] = City{"malafya"}

    go m.Round()

    for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
        go func() {
            time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
            go m.Add("uz", City{"CityMakon"})
            go m.Add("uzb", City{"CityMakon"})
        }()
    }
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    done <- struct{}{}
}
```

the output:

```
----- {Canada}
----- {GB}
----- {malafya}
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Write by goroutine 12:
  runtime.mapassign1()
      /usr/lib/golang/src/runtime/hashmap.go:411 +0x0
  main.(*Map).Add()
      /home/narkoz/elixir/round.go:37 +0xaa

Previous write by goroutine 6:
  runtime.mapdelete()
      /usr/lib/golang/src/runtime/hashmap.go:511 +0x0
  main.(*Map).Round()
      /home/narkoz/elixir/round.go:26 +0x3a9

Goroutine 12 (running) created at:
  main.main.func1()
      /home/narkoz/elixir/round.go:54 +0x8c

Goroutine 6 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /home/narkoz/elixir/round.go:49 +0x2af
==================
----- {CityMakon}
----- {CityMakon}
Found 1 data race(s)
exit status 66
```

But when I change the value type of the map to int or string, there is not data race.

What solution do you recommend ?

Comment: I think that's coincidence about the types affecting results (but maybe someone who knows better will reply). You need locking around the map iteration and delete in `Round()` too.

Comment: Thanks, so I have wrapped the range loop with RLock and RUnlock, this removed the second data race

Comment: The race detector tells you _exactly_ where the race occurred. You're calling `delete` without taking the lock.

Comment: @maksadbek Since there's a `delete` inside that loop, you really need a `Lock`, not just an `RLock`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATES:

> But when I change the value type of the map to int or string, there is not data race.

I tested your code further. Changing the map's value type to int or string continues to yield the race condition. Try run it in a `while` loop on your shell, you will see what I mean:

```
$ while true; do go run -race main.go; done
```

There shouldn't be any differences between the value types.

---

As reported by the race detectors, there are two different race conditions. The first race (which you've fixed) happens between the read (of `i`) at line 54 and the write (to `i`) at line 51. This happens because your goroutine closure holds a reference to `i`, which is changed by the `for` loop in your `main` goroutine. You can resolve it by either getting rid of the `println(">>", i)` or passing `i` into your closure like this:

```
for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
  go func(index int) {
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    println(">>", index)
    go m.Add("uz", City{"CityMakon"})
    go m.Add("uzb", City{"CityMakon"})
  }(i)
}
```

The second race condition happens between the assignment on line 37 (`m.Data[id] = h`) and the delete in line 25 (`delete(m.Data, i)`). The race detector marks this as a race condition because it can't guarantee the [*Happen Before*](https://golang.org/ref/mem#tmp_2) constraint on your code. You can resolve this by either:

Locking the `delete` statement:

```
m.Lock()
delete(m.Data, i)
m.Unlock()
```

Or alternately, extract the two cases in your `Round()` method into two methods, ranging over the channel:

```
func (m *Map) Round() {
  for i, v := range m.Data {
    fmt.Println("-----", v)
    delete(m.Data, i)
  }
}

func (m *Map) Done() {
  for range done {
    println("bye")
    break
  }
}

func main() {
  // ...
  go Round()
  go Done()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved one data race of two. I updated it. But the second data race one still occurs

Comment: (Noting the second race seems to be resolved as well, per your reply to my comment on the question.)